# Show that $f(x)=x^2−3$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I need help finding a partition of $[0,1]$ that works... I'm really stuck here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Find the $\inf\{U(f,P)\}$, which equals integral from $a$ to $b$ of $f(x)$

Comment: Have you ever done an exercise (back in regular calculus) where you used to find the expression for the left-sum or the right-sum for $n$ rectangles?

Comment: Finding **a** partition won't work. "The Enemy" comes with an $\varepsilon > 0$ and you have to provide a partition $P$ (depending on $\varepsilon$) showing that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Another hint: [The graph of $x \mapsto x^2 - 3x + 5$](https://www.google.com/search?q=x^2+-+3*x+%2B+5+from+0+to+2) is piecewise monotone, so calculating $U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)$ is very easy; especially if you take $P$ to contain the minimum of the function.

Comment: @Braindead I believe the left sum is $(20n^2+60n+4)/(3n^2)$ ? Am I doing that correctly?

Comment: And for the record, the definition using upper and lower sums is *not* the Riemann integral (which uses tagged partitions), but rather the [Darboux integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral).  That the two actually compute the same thing is not immediately obvious from the definition.

Comment: So you can't use the left-sum of the entire interval $[0,2]$, because the left-sum is neither the $L$ nor $U$. As @kahen points out, if you look at the graph of $y=x^2-3x+5$ on $[0,2]$, part of it the graph is decreasing (here the left-sum is a $U$, which hopefully you can see by drawing a picture), and part of it is increasing (here, the left-sum is a $L$.). You need to mix and match the left-sum and right-sum so that you'll have a $U$ (or $L$) on the entire $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably difficult to decipher what I wrote up there, so here I'll show you how to get a $U(f,P)$.

We know that $f(x) = x^2 - 3x + 5$ is a parabola, and on $[0,3/2]$ it is decreasing, and $[3/2,2]$ it is increasing. (Do you see why?)

To get a $U$, I am going to choose the left-end points on $[0,3/2]$ and right-end points on $[3/2,2]$. If you are feeling a bit skeptical as to why this is the case, sketch the graph of $x^2-3x+5$. The rectangles that I am choosing contain the area under the curve.

On $[0,3/2]$, we have $h = \frac{3/2 - 0}{n}$ as the width of each rectangle, and each left-end point is going to be $x_k = 0 + k h$, where $i = 0, \dots, n-1$.

So the left-hand sum on $[0,3/2]$ will be:

$$\text{Left-sum on $[0,3/2]$}  =  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x_k) h = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k\frac{3}{2n})\frac{3}{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k^2\frac{9}{4n^2} - k \frac{9}{2n} + 5)\frac{3}{2n}$$

On $[3/2,2]$, we have $h = \frac{2 - 3/2}{n}$ as the width of each rectangle, and each right-end point is going to be $x_k = 3/2 + k h$, where $i = 1, \dots, n$.

So the right-hand sum on $[3/2,2]$ will be:

$$\text{Right-sum on $[3/2,2]$}  =  \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x_k) h = \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(3/2+k\frac{1}{2n})\frac{1}{2n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} ((\frac32+k\frac{1}{2n})^2 - 3(\frac32+k\frac{1}{2n}) + 5)\frac{1}{2n}$$

Let me know if you feel like you are completely lost, and maybe I can clarify some more points.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have broken down the integral into three parts (-x^2, -3x, and 5) and found U(f,P) for each and then added them together. After finding the inf{U(f,p)}, I seem to be getting the desired answer of 20/3.   Your solution is very helpful! To calculate the error where n=10, 20, and 100 should I just be plugging n in to U(f,P)?

Comment: No problem. Yes for the error part. Were you able to finish the other part of the problem? (Showing that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$.)

Comment: yes I was thank you!